# Where should we announce our official launch?

Tags: discussion, beta-essentials

With our launch (theoretically) right around the corner, we should try and see if we can get the official site launch announced and/or covered. Here's a list of places I've thought about:

- Reddit
- Hacker News
- TechCrunch
- LifeHacker
- [The How-To Geek](https://superuser.com/users/4102/the-how-to-geek)
- Daring Fireball
- marco.org (we might have a decent chance here, Marco is on the SO [board of advisors](https://stackoverflow.com/about/management#advisors))

We could also announce it ourselves on the forums of:

- MacRumors
- TiPb
- AppleInsider

Any ideas for other sites to announce it on? Any idea what the wording of the announcement should be?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's great to announce, but I'd also encourage simple organic linking and sharing of relevant questions and answers.

In other words, instead of posting an announcement, find someone that has a problem addressed in the Q&A here, and answer something like:

> I too had this problem, and I found the solution on Apple Stack Exchange
>
> http://example.com/questions/12345/how-to-fix-your-busted-itunes

Related:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

Comment: Oh definitely, that's [been our approach all along](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89/promoting-apple-se/93#93)

Comment: now that the site is live, can you set up askdifferent.com to redirect properly?

Comment: @kyle putting it in the sysadmin room now..

Answer (score 3):

I've submitted it to [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2153660), [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/fazm2/ask_different_a_stack_overflow_site_for_apple/), [Reddit again](http://www.reddit.com/r/reddit.com/comments/fazl8/ask_different_a_stack_overflow_site_for_apple/), [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=11806439#post11806439), [AppleInsider](http://forums.appleinsider.com/showthread.php?p=1796131#post1796131). If you have accounts on those sites, feel free to comment and/or vote up, where applicable.

We've been featured on [MacStories](http://www.macstories.net/news/ask-different-apple-stack-exchange-out-of-beta/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+macstoriesnet+%28MacStories%29):

> The Apple specific question forum as a part of the Stack Exchange community has gone live this afternoon, harboring a community of experts willing to share knowledge on all things iPad, Mac, and iOS development. The collaborate question and answer site has implemented a lovely interface fit for any MacBook or iMac you may be visiting the exchange from, and you can visit Stack Exchange’s most recent launch at apple.stackexchange.com.

Great press, the only thing is that we don't do development questions.

Also, a mention on [The Brooks Review](http://brooksreview.net/2011/01/stack-exchange/):

> [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)
>
> A new site from Stack Exchange for Apple related questions and answers.